# Can I apply user created Roles in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roles, role-base-authorization

I've found tons of examples online that explain how to create roles in MVC 5 using the RoleManager etc, but what I cannot find an answer to, is if it's at all possible to dynamically apply roles created on a user level (through the UI) to parts of the application?

I don't understand the purpose of creating new roles only for them to be stored in the DB with no other function?

Any comments are appreciated.

Here is an example of my role creation code:

```
 public bool CreateRole(string name)
    {
        var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(
            new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var idResult = rm.Create(new IdentityRole(name));
        return idResult.Succeeded;
    }
```

Comment: when you say *dynamically apply roles created on a user level (through the UI) to parts of the application*, what do you mean dynamically. ain't this *CreateRole* method dynamic by nature. Is there a problem with your code or what.

Comment: @PalakBhansali Most examples show authentication like this:

        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
Which is not extendable by the User

Comment: What do you want to extend ? Admin Role or anything regarding roles.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to apply fine-grained authorization using more than just a role attribute? For instance:

- a relationship between the user and the targeted document / resource?
- Time of the day?

In that case you need to move from RBAC to ABAC (attribute-based access control).

NIST has a great page on the topic: [csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/)